# How to call function in a component from a attached directive?

Tags: angular

```html
<app-movie-display (appIsTouching)="doSomething()"></app-movie-display>
```

appIsTouching:

```js
@HostListener('touchstart', ['$event']) public handleTouchStart(): void {
  this.touching = true;
  const startTouch = new Date;

  const touchInterval = setInterval(() => {
    const currentTime = new Date
    const timeDifference = currentTime.getTime() - startTouch.getTime()

    if (!this.touching) {
      clearInterval(touchInterval)
    }

    if (timeDifference > 600) {
      clearInterval(touchInterval)
      this.newItemEvent.emit();
    }
  }, 25);
}
```

What I want to do is call a `doSomething()` on the component the `appIsTouching` directive is attached to. But I'm getting the error:

> Property 'doSomething' does not exist on type 'MovieDashboardComponent'.

`MovieDashboardComponent` is the component in which I the `<app-movie-display ...>` in the template. So the error makes sense because `EventEmitter` goes to the parent.

How do I call a function in the component the directive is attached to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with this approach https://medium.com/@redin.gaetan/angular-15-hostdirectives-510e8a1fa456

The component:

```js
@Component({
  ...
  hostDirectives: [IsTouchingDirective]
})
export class MovieDisplayComponent {
  public constructor(
    private touchingDirective: IsTouchingDirective = inject(IsTouchingDirective, {self: true})
  ) {
    this.touchingDirective.appIsTouching.subscribe({
      next: () => this.toggleDisplay()
    })
  }

  public toggleDisplay(): void {
    this.showDetails = !this.showDetails
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using template variables:

```html
<app-movie-display #display (appIsTouching)="display.doSomething()"></app-movie-display>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an @Output property in the directive and emit an event to the parent component in the component that the appIsTouching directive is attached to. The parent component can then listen to this event and call the doSomething() function.

touching.directive:

```
@Output() appIsTouchingEvent = new EventEmitter();

if (timeDifference > 600) {
  clearInterval(touchInterval)
  this.appIsTouchingEvent.emit();
}
```

component.component:

```
<app-movie-display (appIsTouching)="onAppIsTouching()"></app-movie-display>

// ...

onAppIsTouching() {
  this.doSomething();
}

doSomething() {
  // Your function implementation
}
```